# Div out of position when animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mobile

I have a simple animation where 2 images and 1 div move.
The website in question is: [sociometric.me](http://sociometric.me)

The problem is, when animation starts the div containing "sociometric.me" text goes down, and because the problem occurs in mobile I can't check DOM.
The problem does not occur with chrome, but iOS Safari and Android Default browser seems to exhibit this behaviour.

Here's a part of code for animation:

animation code:

```
$(".logo-text").animate({
                left: "-=18em",
                top: "+=10em",
                opacity: "0"
            }, 3000, function () {});
```

css:

```
 .logo-text {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 9em;
    -ms-transform: rotate(-39deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-39deg); /* Safari */
    transform: rotate(-39deg);
    width: 14em;
    letter-spacing: 0.4em;
    font-family: GothicBold;
    margin: 0 auto;

}
```

The website was intended for mobile use, that's why it looks terrible on desktops. Any help also regarding this is also appreciated...

Comment: You can inspect your android code through remote debugging in Chrome. See link for more info https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/

Comment: @StephenLane problem only occurs with default browsers (I suspect using webkit)